# Should it be possible to execute an SQL function in a check constraint within DB2 z/OS

Tags: function, db2, constraints, zos

Simple version of the DDL:

```
create function rm00dv1.no_concurrent_schedules() 
returns integer
LANGUAGE SQL
READS SQL DATA
NO EXTERNAL ACTION
NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    declare num_overlaps integer;

    select count(*)
    into num_overlaps
    from 
        rm00dv1.schedules a
    where
        a.id != 0
        and
        exists (
            select 1
            from rm00dv1.schedules b
            where
                b.id = 0 -- matches the key of a given record
                and rm00dv1.isConcurrent(b.schdl_eff_dt, b.schdl_trm_dt, a.schdl_eff_dt, a.schdl_trm_dt) != 0
        );

    return num_overlaps;    
end;
```

Table:

```
create table rm00dv1.schedules (
    id int not null,
    schdl_eff_dt date not null,
    schdl_trm_dt date not null,
    info_chg_ts timestamp(6) not null with default
    )
in RM00DV1.TSRMDV01 ;


alter table rm00dv1.schedules add constraint no_schedule_overlap
check ((schdl_trm_dt < '01/01/2015')
       or
       rm00dv1.no_concurrent_schedules() <= 0);
```

I am getting an `SQL00551N - no execution privilege` and that is odd because I can execute the function in a select statement.

Any idea to solve this problem? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can't. I'm looking at [the DB2 10 for z/OS reference for ALTER TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_altertable.html) reference and it says the following under **CHECK (check-condition)**: "A *check-condition* is a search condition, with the following restrictions: ... must not contain... Built-in or user-defined functions...".

Since your function looks like it won't convert to a check condition, defining triggers on the table might be the next best option.

Comment: Darn. I read over that doc, but missed that bullet. Thanks.  FYI, when I stub-in a built-in function, min(1,0), I get an error message that makes sense, check constraint is invalid.  So, regardless of privileges on WLM, this approach is not going to work.

Comment: FYI, a trigger by itself is not going to work either because the validity of the insert or update operation is dependent on values already in the table and you can't access the table. I ran into this, http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n746.html

Comment: @ChrisGolledge May I ask how you ended up solving the problem?

Comment: It remains unsolved. I had a thought to try using a materialized query table with deferred update and accessing that from the body of the before trigger, but those require an index, and my DBAs have not granted me privilege to create indices. A thought for the future is to create new tables containing a PERIOD BUSINESS_TIME NO OVERLAP column.

Comment: @ChrisGolledge Try defining a view as SELECT * FROM RM00DV1.SCHEDULES and defining INSTEAD OF INSERT/UPDATE triggers on that view. You might be able to reference the SCHEDULES table that way. I did some naive testing and results seem promising.

Comment: Good idea about the INSTEAD OF, but the users sometimes edit the data with adhoc query tools, and training them to access the view and never the table would be uncertain.

Answer (score 0):

I learned that AFTER triggers do not get a -746 like BEFORE triggers do. I had really wanted to use a CONSTRAINT because that best captures the intent for people who come after me, with a BEFORE trigger to terminate the active schedules. But, it looks like a sequence of triggers is going to be the way to go.  It is a bit clunky because the triggers all have to be created separately and you have to look at them together to get the intent, and because correct behavior is dependent on their creation order. Yes, it is documented that they will be executed in the order of their creation.

Happy path termination of rows without a specified termination date:

```
CREATE TRIGGER terminate_no_trm
after 
INSERT ON schedules
referencing new as new
FOR EACH ROW 
MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
update schedules 
set 
    schdl_trm_dt = max(schdl_eff_dt, new.schdl_eff_dt - 1 days) -- prob not necessary, but don't set the trm before the eff
    , info_chg_ts = new.info_chg_ts
where
    new.keyCombo = keyCombo
    and
    schdl_trm_dt = '9999-12-31'
    and schdl_eff_dt < new.schdl_eff_dt;

end
```

Prevent insert of rows if that insert causes an overlap:

```
CREATE TRIGGER no_overlapping_schedules_i
after 
insert ON schedules
referencing new as n
FOR EACH ROW
MODE DB2SQL

when (num_concurrent_schedules(n.keyCombo) > 0)
begin atomic
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '75001' (
    'Concurrent schedules detected: ' 

    concat ' ' concat cast(n.keyCombo as varchar(32))
    concat ':  ' concat cast(n.schdl_eff_dt as varchar(32))
    concat ' to ' concat cast(n.schdl_trm_dt as varchar(32))
    );
end
```

and prevent UPDATE if that would result in an overlap

```
CREATE TRIGGER no_overlapping_schedules_u
after 
update ON schedules
referencing new as n
FOR EACH ROW
MODE DB2SQL

when (num_concurrent_schedules(n.keyCombo) > 0)
begin atomic
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '75001' (
    'Concurrent schedules detected: ' 
    concat ' ' concat cast(n.keyCombo as varchar(32))
    concat ':  ' concat cast(n.schdl_eff_dt as varchar(32))
    concat ' to ' concat cast(n.schdl_trm_dt as varchar(32))
    );
end
```

Thanks for the ideas.